# Linq to Sql generates code that times out

Tags: entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

The SQL being generated by my linq statement is timing out.  The manual SQL I write completes in less than a second.

I'm trying to write the following SQL statement with linq:

```sql
SELECT MONTH(s.modified), s.site, s.campus, s.className, s.old, s.barcode, l.name, COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Scrapped s
JOIN dbo.Location l ON s.barcode = l.spaceBarcode AND l.type = 'lab'
WHERE s.modified >= '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY MONTH(s.modified), s.site, s.campus, s.className, s.old, s.barcode, l.name
```

So I wrote it like this:

```cs
from s in context.Scrapped.AsNoTracking()
join l in context.Location on new { type = "lab", spaceBarcode = s.barcode } equals new { l.type, l.spaceBarcode }
where s.modified >= date
group new { s, l } by new { s.modified.Month, s.site, s.campus, s.className, s.old, s.barcode, l.name } into grp
select new Scrapped2DTO {
    Month = grp.Key.Month,
    Site = grp.Key.site,
    Class = grp.Key.className,
    Barcode = grp.Key.barcode,
    Campus = grp.Key.campus,
    Old = grp.Key.old,
    Name = grp.Key.name,
    Count = grp.Count()
};
```

That generates with an extra level of select, making it take minutes to complete vs. a second.  How do I rewrite my query so this doesn't happen?  It's generating this SQL

```sql
SELECT [t].[Month], N'' AS [MonthName], [t].[site] AS [Site], [t].[className] AS [Class], [t].[barcode] AS [Barcode], [t].[campus] AS [Campus], [t].[old] AS [Old], [t].[name] AS [Name], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM (
    SELECT [s].[barcode], [s].[campus], [s].[className], [s].[old], [s].[site], [s0].[name], DATEPART(month, [s].[modified]) AS [Month]
    FROM [Scrapped] AS [s]
    INNER JOIN [Location] AS [s0] ON N'lab' = [s0].[type] AND ([s].[barcode] = [s0].[spaceBarcode] OR (([s].[barcode] IS NULL) AND ([s0].[spaceBarcode] IS NULL)))
    WHERE [s].[modified] >= @__date_0
) AS [t]
GROUP BY [t].[Month], [t].[site], [t].[campus], [t].[className], [t].[old], [t].[barcode], [t].[name]
```

Comment: What happens if you change `new { s, l }` to `1`?

Comment: Also, what LINQ are you using: EF 4.x / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x / 7.x / 8.x? What database provider?

Comment: @NetMage I'm using EF6.  Changing the group to 1 doesn't seem to make any difference.